# unable to install homebrew in mac os

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am unable to install homebrew in my macOS:

My input and output in terminal was:

```
apalyas-MacBook-pro:~ apalya$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==>This script will install
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site_function/_brew
/usr/local/hombrew

press RETURN or any other key to abort
==> downloading and installing homebrew...
mkdir: /usr/local/Library: permission denied
failed during: /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: try running the command with `sudo`

Comment: thanks for the reply @M.S.P,  how to use sudo for that install, can u explain clearly

Comment: try running `sudo apalya$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: sudo: apalya$: command not found

Comment: I am sorry for that, kindly check my answer. I have modified the command

Comment: `chown -R $USER /usr/local` is the way to go. After that retry installing. Don't use sudo, this is not the way mac works.

Comment: I suspect the problem is *System Integrity Protection* which you need to disable before you can install `homebrew` - see http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 3):

You just needs to set your user as an Administrator in System Preferences, Users & Groups and mark the checkbox Allow user to administer this computer.

This allow me to install Brew.

Answer (score 0):

If even after getting Admin privileges or using sudo does not work then one can go with Git option.

On the Homebrew website they have provided one more option to install it via Git. So if you have git installed on your system then you can use either

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

or:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
```

then:

```
eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
brew update --force --quiet
chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"
```

Make sure you avoid installing into:

```
Directories with names that contain spaces. Homebrew itself can handle spaces, but many build scripts cannot.
/tmp subdirectories because Homebrew gets upset.
/sw and /opt/local because build scripts get confused when Homebrew is there instead of Fink or MacPorts, respectively.
```

https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score -2):

After reading the stack trace, it clearly states that

```
enter mkdir: /usr/local/Library: permission denied
failed during: /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-corecode
```

In order to get appropriate permission, you need to run the command as superuser. In order to execute command as superuser, you need to use the keyword `sudo` before the command.

And hence the command becomes

```
sudo /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Update:** Homebrew needs administrator privileges and not root, and so follow this sequence:

**1. Give Local User the root permission**

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

**2. Execute Homebrew command**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

If you want more knowledge regarding this, refer [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct) article.

Comment: don't run this as root!

Comment: hi M.S.P it was raising the error like don;t run this as root

Comment: @Ram, I have edited my post. Kindly have a look at it and do upvote it and mark it correct, if your problem is solved. Thank you :)